# Calculating Trapezoid's three equal sides with just knowing: base and height?

Tags: trigonometry

It is really an architectural problem. For example when you have a bay window and you want to find out the three equal sides of bay window by just having window opening size and how far out is protruding [Bay window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZJfp.jpg)

That what I'm trying to calculate: the given are the base and the height.
I want to calculate three equal sides of the trapezoid.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

The trapezoid can be labelled as follows, where $b$ is the base, $h$ is the height, and $k$ is the length of one of the three equal sides.

[image]

When the altitude $h$ is dropped, there is a gap between where it touches the base and where $k$ touches it. Let the length of this gap be $g$. Then
$$g=\sqrt{k^2-h^2}$$
and
$$b=k+2g$$
so
$$b=k+2\sqrt{k^2-h^2}$$
And we want to solve this for $k$.
$$b-k=2\sqrt{k^2-h^2}$$
$$(b-k)^2=4(k^2-h^2)$$
$$b^2-2kb+k^2=4k^2-4h^2$$
$$=3k^2+2bk-4h^2-b^2$$
Then solve using the quadratic formula:
$$k=\frac{-2b+\sqrt{4b^2-4(3)(-4h^2-b^2)}}{6}$$
$$k=\frac{-2b+\sqrt{4b^2+12(4h^2+b^2)}}{6}$$
$$k=\frac{-2b+\sqrt{16b^2+48h^2}}{6}$$
$$k=\frac{-2b+4\sqrt{b^2+3h^2}}{6}$$
$$k=\frac{-b+2\sqrt{b^2+3h^2}}{3}$$
I believe that this is the answer.

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what it is. I have been battling with this question repeatedly. Coming up with the answer= Genious and following the formula pretty straight forward. Just for my future information- in the beginning, to solve for "g" you used Pythagorean theorem and what is the second line? Is that a formula for the trapezoid. I never came across that before.

Comment: No, it is the same as my $x+2y=L$. side is $k$ this is the length between the dashed lines, and there are 2 parts outside the dashed lines, of same length $g$. When you add all in order this gives $b=g+k+g=k+2g$ where $b$ is the whole aperture.

Comment: @AdrianWysocki Since I defined $g$ as the gap between the altitude and one of the sides where they intersect the base, and since the top is parallel to the base and there are two identical gaps on either side of the base, the length of the base is equal to the length of the top plus two gap lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Let the base be $b$, the height $h$, the length to be found $a$, and the angle between the base and the sloping sides be $\theta$. (Similar triangles implies both such angles are the same). Then we have the two equations
$$ h = a\sin{\theta}, \\
b = a+2a\cos{\theta}. $$
We now eliminate $\theta$: we have
$$a^2\sin^2{\theta} = h^2, \qquad a^2\cos^2{\theta} = \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}, $$
and then adding and using the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}=1$ gives
$$ 4a^2 = 4h^2+(b-a)^2, $$
(we could get to here by using just Pythagoras and the length from the corner to the foot of the perpendicular), so
$$ 3a^2 +2ba = 4h^2+b^2 $$
Completing the square gives
$$ (a+b/3)^2 + \frac{b^2}{9} = \frac{4h^2+b^2}{3}, $$
so
$$ a = \frac{-b \pm 2\sqrt{3h^2+b^2}}{3} $$
Of course we want a positive root since $a$ is a length, so we have to take the $+$.

Comment: Another Amazing way, to calculate Trapezoid three equal sides.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $L=230$ the opening size and $h=66$ the protruding depth.

I'll call $x$ the sides and $y$ the complement, i.e. $x+2y=L$.

Applying pythagoras' theorem in one of the rectangle triangle we have $y^2+h^2=x^2$

Now we solve in $y$ : $y^2+h^2=L^2-4Ly+4y^2\iff3y^2-4Ly+L^2-h^2=0$

$\Delta=16L^2-12(L^2-h^2)=4L^2(1+\frac{3h^2}{L^2})$

$y=\frac{4L-2L\sqrt{1+\frac{3h^2}{L^2}}}{6}$

> $\displaystyle x=L-2y=\frac L3(2\sqrt{1+\frac{3h^2}{L^2}}-1)$

Comment: Amazing, slightly more difficult to follow as a non-mathematician, but the result is correct.

Comment: The only difference with other answers is that I factorized $L$ outside the square root. If you put it back you get $\frac{2\sqrt{L^2+3h^2}-L}3$ which is Frpzzd formula with different letters.